# Why does this SQL Server query not return the intended result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table, meant to depict transactions:

```
noconta    |numerario|dataefectivacao    |datarealizacao     |tipomov|descricao                                           |
-----------|---------|-------------------|-------------------|-------|----------------------------------------------------|
11111111111|       58|2018-10-26 00:00:00|2018-10-24 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 6-1 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)|
11111111111|       11|2018-12-27 00:00:00|2018-10-25 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 7-1 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito) |
11111111111|       24|2018-12-14 00:00:00|2018-12-12 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 1-1 (Crédito)                    |
11111111111|       42|2018-12-16 00:00:00|2018-12-13 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 2-1 (Crédito)                    |
11111111111|       44|2018-12-17 00:00:00|2018-12-14 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 4-1 (Débito)                     |
11111111111|       31|2018-12-15 00:00:00|2018-12-18 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 5-1 (Débito)                     |
11111111111|       55|2018-12-22 00:00:00|2018-12-19 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 3-1 (Crédito)                    |
22222222222|       45|2018-10-24 00:00:00|2018-10-22 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 6-2 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)|
22222222222|      241|2018-12-12 00:00:00|2018-12-10 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 1-2 (Crédito)                    |
22222222222|       12|2018-12-14 00:00:00|2018-12-11 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 2-2 (Crédito)                    |
22222222222|       35|2018-12-15 00:00:00|2018-12-12 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 4-2 (Débito)                     |
22222222222|       22|2018-12-16 00:00:00|2018-12-13 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 5-2 (Débito)                     |
22222222222|       31|2018-12-20 00:00:00|2018-12-17 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 3-2 (Crédito)                    |
22222222222|       23|2018-10-25 00:00:00|2018-12-23 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 7-2 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito) |
33333333333|       51|2018-10-22 00:00:00|2018-10-20 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 6-3 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)|
33333333333|      241|2018-12-09 00:00:00|2018-12-07 00:00:00|      0|Movimento Genérico 1-3 (Crédito)                    |
33333333333|       15|2018-12-13 00:00:00|2018-12-10 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 4-3 (Débito)                     |
33333333333|       41|2018-12-14 00:00:00|2018-12-11 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 5-3 (Débito)                     |
33333333333|       92|2018-10-23 00:00:00|2018-12-21 00:00:00|      1|Movimento Genérico 7-3 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito) |
```

How would one write a query that intends to return the account numbers ("noconta") for which the **SUM of numerario** (for that account) is greater for credit (`tipomov=0`) than for debit (`tipomov=1`) during December 2018?

Here was my attempt at it. While that it raises no errors, the result is empty (Which is easy to check that shouldn't be the case on the example given). In fact, it's empty independently of checking for a greater, equal or lesser sum.

```
SELECT noconta 
FROM MOVIMENTO 
WHERE ((SELECT YEAR(datarealizacao)) = 2018 
       AND (SELECT MONTH (datarealizacao))= 12) 
GROUP BY noconta, tipomov
HAVING ((SELECT SUM(numerario) WHERE tipomov = 0) > (SELECT SUM(numerario) WHERE tipomov = 1));
```

Comment: Try my answer. That will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #MOVIMENTO (noconta BIGINT,numerario INT, dataefectivacao DATETIME,datarealizacao DATETIME,tipomov INT,descricao NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','58','2018-10-26 00:00:00','2018-10-24 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 6-1 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','11','2018-12-27 00:00:00','2018-10-25 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 7-1 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito) ')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','24','2018-12-14 00:00:00','2018-12-12 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 1-1 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','42','2018-12-16 00:00:00','2018-12-13 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 2-1 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','44','2018-12-17 00:00:00','2018-12-14 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 4-1 (Débito) ')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','31','2018-12-15 00:00:00','2018-12-18 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 5-1 (Débito) ')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('11111111111','55','2018-12-22 00:00:00','2018-12-19 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 3-1 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','45','2018-10-24 00:00:00','2018-10-22 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 6-2 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','241','2018-12-12 00:00:00','2018-12-10 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 1-2 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','12','2018-12-14 00:00:00','2018-12-11 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 2-2 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','35','2018-12-15 00:00:00','2018-12-12 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 4-2 (Débito) ')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','22','2018-12-16 00:00:00','2018-12-13 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 5-2 (Débito) ')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','31','2018-12-20 00:00:00','2018-12-17 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 3-2 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('22222222222','23','2018-10-25 00:00:00','2018-12-23 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 7-2 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('33333333333','51','2018-10-22 00:00:00','2018-10-20 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 6-3 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('33333333333','241','2018-12-09 00:00:00','2018-12-07 00:00:00','0','Movimento Genérico 1-3 (Crédito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('33333333333','15','2018-12-13 00:00:00','2018-12-10 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 4-3 (Débito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('33333333333','41','2018-12-14 00:00:00','2018-12-11 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 5-3 (Débito)')
INSERT INTO #MOVIMENTO VALUES('33333333333','92','2018-10-23 00:00:00','2018-12-21 00:00:00','1','Movimento Genérico 7-3 (Não Dezembro 2018) (Débito)')
```

**TSQL Query:**

```
SELECT noconta 
FROM #MOVIMENTO
WHERE '2018-12-01' <= datarealizacao and datarealizacao < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY noconta
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tipomov = 0 THEN numerario END)>SUM(CASE WHEN tipomov = 1 THEN numerario END)
```

**Output:**

```
noconta
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
```

Comment: You may want to consider making the `WHERE` clause [SARGable](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/09/13/what-is-a-sargable-predicate/) so that it can benefit from indexes: `where '2018-12-01' <= datarealizacao and datarealizacao < '2019-01-01'`.

Comment: @HABO, Thank you!!!. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll follow this hereafter.

Comment: @DineshDB, I would love to see what Habo suggested in your answer... Do you mind changing it accordingly? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the case when there are credits but no debits for an account number, during Dec. 2018. Building on [DineshDB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3876565/dineshdb) answer, you could consider the following:

```
SELECT noconta
  FROM #MOVIMENTO
WHERE datarealizacao >= '2018-12-01' 
  AND datarealizacao < '2019-01-01'
  GROUP BY noconta
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tipomov = 0 THEN numerario END)>ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tipomov = 1 THEN numerario END), 0)
```

Comment: Note that if `datarealizacao` has a non-zero time on the last day of the month it will not be included. It will always be handled correctly if you use a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) by adding one day to the end of the range, but excluding the endpoint: `datarealizacao < '2019-01-01'`.

Comment: @HABO, Thank you, you're absoluterly right. I missed that. I have updated my answer.